# Magento2 : How to override FinalPrice.php file in Magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides

I want to override

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/FinalPrice.php

with constructor argument.

> **Note :** File overriding is working fine but when I create constructor in the overridden file it is giving me an error.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass parent constructor with your original class argument **vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/FinalPrice.php**

like

```
class A {
  public function __construct(Abc $abc){

  }
}

class B extends A {
  public function __construct(Abc $abc,Xyz $xyz){
      parent::__construct($abc);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please first check the file after reply, you can see there is a file and interface extended already.

Comment: @MagentoDev you need to pass your parent class argument in the constructor.